# many CSS text shadows

Tags: css

I tried to make a "text border" with CSS text-shadow. Finally there are 121 shadows:

```
    text-shadow:
-5px -5px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),-4px -5px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),-3px -5px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),-2px -5px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),-1px -5px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),0 -5px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),1px -5px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),2px -5px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),3px -5px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),4px -5px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),5px -5px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),
-5px -4px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),-4px -4px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),-3px -4px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),-2px -4px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),-1px -4px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),0 -4px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),1px -4px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),2px -4px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),3px -4px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),4px -4px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),5px -4px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),
-5px -3px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),-4px -3px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),-3px -3px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),-2px -3px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),-1px -3px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),0 -3px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),1px -3px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),2px -3px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),3px -3px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),4px -3px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),5px -3px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),
-5px -2px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),-4px -2px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),-3px -2px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),-2px -2px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),-1px -2px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),0 -2px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),1px -2px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),2px -2px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),3px -2px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),4px -2px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),5px -2px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),
-5px -1px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),-4px -1px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),-3px -1px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),-2px -1px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),-1px -1px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),0 -1px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),1px -1px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),2px -1px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),3px -1px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),4px -1px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),5px -1px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),
-5px 0 0 var(--grau_dunkel),-4px 0 0 var(--grau_dunkel),-3px 0 0 var(--grau_dunkel),-2px 0 0 var(--grau_dunkel),-1px 0 0 var(--grau_dunkel),1px 0 0 var(--grau_dunkel),2px 0 0 var(--grau_dunkel),3px 0 0 var(--grau_dunkel),4px 0 0 var(--grau_dunkel),5px 0 0 var(--grau_dunkel),
-5px 1px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),-4px 1px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),-3px 1px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),-2px 1px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),-1px 1px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),0 1px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),1px 1px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),2px 1px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),3px 1px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),4px 1px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),5px 1px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),
-5px 2px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),-4px 2px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),-3px 2px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),-2px 2px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),-1px 2px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),0 2px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),1px 2px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),2px 2px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),3px 2px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),4px 2px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),5px 2px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),
-5px 3px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),-4px 3px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),-3px 3px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),-2px 3px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),-1px 3px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),0 3px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),1px 3px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),2px 3px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),3px 3px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),4px 3px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),5px 3px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),
-5px 4px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),-4px 4px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),-3px 4px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),-2px 4px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),-1px 4px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),0 4px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),1px 4px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),2px 4px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),3px 4px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),4px 4px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),5px 4px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),
-5px 5px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),-4px 5px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),-3px 5px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),-2px 5px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),-1px 5px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),0 5px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),1px 5px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),2px 5px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),3px 5px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),4px 5px 0 var(--grau_dunkel),5px 5px 0 var(--grau_dunkel);
```

Is this generally bad, are there too many shadows or does it work anyways?

Comment: It's likely to have *performance issues* but this is opinion-based.

Comment: why exactly 121 ? and not 120 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not forbidden by the specification, some people would tell you that this code is unreadable, so you should consider generating such construction automatically using tools like LESS or SASS if you want code looking good.

What about performance issues, I'd avoid that if animations are involved (even those achieved by combining scrolling with things like `vh` dimensions or `poisition:fixed`) but it should be perfectly fine if the text does not need to be re-rendered while the page is opened.

It may need checking in practice thou if it impacts the site in your case or not as it is hard to tell in a general case. Test especially how it behaves in Firefox as Chrome seems to optimize such things better, so FF may be the bottleneck.